# Onedrive sync folders and files without downloading them in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nautilus, configuration, online-storage

After a few years I have installed Ubuntu again and I'm trying to configure it to my liking. I own a Microsoft account with 1 TB cloud storage. I've installed the Onedrive client on Ubuntu but it seems that it downloads all the files and I don't have enough space in my laptop to store them so I just want to use Onedrive in the same way Nautilus and Google Drive work, by pointing to the files without downloading until I click on the files to open them.
Is there any configuration I should try? I've googled for a while and I haven't figured out how to do it.
By the way, how do you start OnedriveGUI? I installed it but I don't know how to start the GUI again.

Comment: these are the insructions for installing OneDrive on Ubuntu. Are these the steps you have taken? https://credibledev.com/install-onedrive-gui-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes, I installed OneDrive and OneDriveGui, and they work but the are downloading the files to my SSD, and I don't have room for that amount of data in that device. Is there a way to use it in the same way than Google Drive? Am I skipping something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> I've installed the Onedrive client on Ubuntu but it seems that it downloads all the files and I don't have enough space in my laptop to store them so I just want to use Onedrive in the same way Nautilus and Google Drive work, by pointing to the files without downloading until I click on the files to open them. Is there any configuration I should try?

The capability you are looking for is the 'on-demand' functionality. It is a pending feature request, please read https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/757 for details.

Alternatively, you can use the application configuration to only 'sync' data that you actually need. Please read 'skip_file', 'skip_dir' and 'sync_list' documentation areas.

To use this capability today, this is implemented via the 'onedriver' OneDrive Client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - it provides the native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.

You cannot use 'onedrive' and 'onedriver' at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about OneDriver, from what I've read it might be what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try this weekend.

Comment: @Juan if that answers your question, please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking on the grey tick alongside it. This will help others with the same question to find the response easily.